# how to sort array of objects based on id and name

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I want to sort Below array based on `name`,`receiver_id`,`sender_id` and `role_id`

```
this.role_id = 3
this.Data = [
    {receiver_id: 3,sender_id:4,name: 'john',},
    {receiver_id: 4,sender_id:3,name: 'james'},
    {receiver_id: 2,sender_id:3,name: 'jane'},
    {receiver_id: null,sender_id:null,name: 'charles'},
    {receiver_id: null,sender_id:null,name: 'aaron'},
    {receiver_id: 2,sender_id:4,name: 'alex'},
    {receiver_id: 3,sender_id:2,name: 'david'},
];
```

I want array objects with `receiver_id == role_id` or `sender_id == role_id` to be on top of array and also it should be in alphabetical order. like this

```
this.Data = [
    {receiver_id: 3,sender_id:2,name: 'david'},
    {receiver_id: 4,sender_id:3,name: 'james'},
    {receiver_id: 2,sender_id:3,name: 'jane'},
    {receiver_id: 3,sender_id:4,name: 'john'},
    {receiver_id: null,sender_id:null,name: 'aaron'},
    {receiver_id: 2,sender_id:4,name: 'alex'},
    {receiver_id: null,sender_id:null,name: 'charles'},
];
```

as of now I can sort based on name only

```
let colName = 'name'
this.Data.sort((b, a) => a[colName] < b[colName] ? 1 : a[colName] > b[colName] ? -1 : 0)
```

how to do this?

Comment: The desired output is not in alphabetical order though?

Comment: it is in order actually, objects with receiver_id = 3 or sender_id = 3 in the desired result are on top. first priority goes to id and then alphabet.

Comment: It's in `sender_id` order first. That's the only property that is in order for the whole array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might help to factor the conditions into functions. `vip` means the object satisfies the numerical test. The other key idea is that vip *sameness* defaults to the alpha sort. This way we get the alpha sort amongst both vips and non-vips.

```js
let role_id = 3
let data = [
    {receiver_id: 3,sender_id:4,name: 'john',},
    {receiver_id: 4,sender_id:3,name: 'james'},
    {receiver_id: 2,sender_id:3,name: 'jane'},
    {receiver_id: 2,sender_id:4,name: 'alex'},
    {receiver_id: 3,sender_id:2,name: 'david'},
];

function diff(a, b) {
  const vip = obj => (role_id === obj.receiver_id) || (role_id === obj.sender_id)
  const vipA = vip(a), vipB = vip(b)
  return vipA === vipB ? a.name.localeCompare(b.name) : (vipA ? -1 : 1)
}

console.log(data.sort(diff))
```

Answer (score 0):

With the sort method you determine if an item A goes before or after the other (B). First you need to define priorities, based on your description I guess:

1º: items where receiver_id == role_id || sender_id == role_id, ordered alphabetically

2º: items where receiver_id != role_id && sender_id != role_id, ordered alphabetically

That would be:

```
this.Data.sort( (a, b) => {

    let conditionForA = a.receiver_id == role_id || a.sender_id == role_id;
    let conditionForB = b.receiver_id == role_id || b.sender_id == role_id;

    if (conditionForA && !conditionForB) {
        // A > B
        return 1;
    }
    if (conditionForB && !conditionForA) {
        // B > A
        return -1;
    }

    // For now A = B, let's compare alphabetically
    if (a.name > b.name) return 1;
    else if (a.name < b.name) return -1;
    return 0; //equal

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
this.Data.filter(a => (a.receiver_id === 3 || a.sender_id === 3))
         .sort((b, a) => a.name < b.name ? 1 : a.name > b.name ? -1 : 0)
    .concat(
this.Data.filter(a => !(a.receiver_id === 3 || a.sender_id === 3))
         .sort((b, a) => a.name < b.name ? 1 : a.name > b.name ? -1 : 0))
```

First, we filter only those entries which satisfy the condition `receiver_id == role_id || sender_id == role_id`, then we sort them by name.

We do the same for those entries which do not satisfy the condition.
And finally we concatenate the two resulting arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You can first sort them after thier "sender_id" and then iterrate over them and sort Alphabetically. Note that the code below is not perfect an can probably writtern more efficent.

Example:

```
 function sort(array) {
 // returns function if array is undefined or empty
 if(!array) return;

 let finalList = [];

 let swapped = false;

 do {
     swapped = false;

     for(let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
         if(array[i].sender_id < array[i - 1].sender_id) {
             let temp = array[i];
             array[i] = array[i - 1];
             array[i - 1] = temp;

             swapped = true;
         }
     } 
 } while (swapped);

 // sorts alphabetic
 let lastBucket = [];
 let lastId = 1;

 for(entry in array) {
     if(array[entry].sender_id > lastId) {
         lastId = array[entry].sender_id;
         let swapped = false;

         do {
             swapped = false;

             for(let i = lastBucket.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
                 if(lastBucket[i].name < lastBucket[i - 1].name) {
                     let temp = lastBucket[i];
                     lastBucket[i] = lastBucket[i - 1];
                     lastBucket[i - 1] = temp;
                     swapped = true;
                 }
             }

             for (item in lastBucket) {
                 finalList.push(lastBucket[item]);
             }

             lastBucket = [];
         } while(swapped);
     }
     lastBucket.push(array[entry]);
 }

 for(item in lastBucket) {
     finalList.push(lastBucket[item]);
 }

 return finalList;
 
 }

 // Test data
 const sampleArray = [
 {
     sender_id: 1,
     name: "test"
 },
 {
     sender_id: 3,
     name: "abc"
 },
 {
     sender_id: 2,
     name: "acd"
 },
 {
     sender_id: 1,
     name: "qqqqq"
 },
 {
     sender_id: 9,
     name: "hello world"
 },
 {
     sender_id: 1,
     name: "abc"
 }
 ]
 let sorted = sort(sampleArray);
```